# Right adjoint is fully faithful iff the counit is an isomorphism (without Yoneda)

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Exercise 2.12(a) from Leinster:

> Show that for any adjunction, the right adjoint is full and faithful if and only if the counit is an isomorphism.

Note: The exercise is given before the chapter on representables and the Yoneda lemma, so I wouldn't like to use those. There is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726117/f-dashv-g-and-g-fully-faithful-implies-counit-is-natural-isomorphism) which partly covers what I'm asking, but the answer uses the Yoneda lemma and other stuff from [Chapter 4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) (whereas this exercise is from Chapter 2).

---

Suppose $F:\mathscr A\to \mathscr B,\ G:\mathscr B\to\mathscr A$ are functors and $F\dashv G$. So there is a bijection $$\mathscr B(F(A),B)\cong\mathscr A(A,G(B))$$ denoted by $f\mapsto \bar f$ in either direction. The counit of adjunction is the natural transformation $$\epsilon: FG\to 1_\mathscr B$$ whose component at $B\in\mathscr B$ is   $$\epsilon_B=\overline{1_{G(B)}}:FG(B)\to B.$$

The question asks to prove that $G$ is full and faithful iff $\epsilon$ is a natural isomorphism. The latter happens iff $\epsilon_B$ is an isomorphism in $\mathscr B$ for all $B\in\mathscr B$. So it suffices to show that $G$ is full and faithful iff each $\epsilon_B$ is an isomorphism.

---

I really don't see how to prove either direction. For example, suppose $G$ is fully faithful. Then there is a bijection $$\mathscr B(B,B')\cong \mathscr A(G(B),G(B'))$$ for all $B,B'\in\mathscr B$. Thus there is also a sequence of bijections

$$\mathscr B(B,B')\cong \mathscr A(G(B),G(B'))\cong \mathscr B(FG(B),B')$$
(the cited question calls these bijections natural isomorphisms, but at this point Leinster doesn't even interpret the adjunction bijection (the second bijection above) as a natural transformation (he only gives some "naturality conditions" which at this point are not interpreted as a natural isomorphism; and I also treat the first $\cong$ above as a mere bijection).

So every arrow $g:B\to B'$ corresponds in a unique way to an arrow $FG(B)\to B'$. But (1) I don't know any explicit formula for this correspondence (the first $\cong$ is just applying $G$; the second is taking bar, but there is no explicit definition of a bar in Leinter's text), and (2) even if I knew the explicit correspondence law, I don't see how it would help me.

The other direction is also not clear.

Addition: the naturality conditions in Leinster's notation:

[image]

Comment: To clarify, when he says "natural isomorphism," he doesn't mean that there is a natural transformation lurking there. Rather, "natural" in this context implies that the correspondence is functorial in both variables, in some sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This result uses the naturalness of the map
$$ \Phi \colon \mathrm{Hom}(A,GB) \xrightarrow\sim \mathrm{Hom}(FA,B). $$
In particular, if $f\colon A\to GB$ and $g\colon B\to B’$, then $\Phi(G(g)f)=g\Phi(f)$. Since $\varepsilon_B=\Phi(\mathrm{id}_{GB})$, we see that $\Phi(G(g))=g\varepsilon_B$.

Thus the map you are interested in
$$ \mathrm{Hom}(B,B') \to \mathrm{Hom}(GB,GB') \xrightarrow\sim \mathrm{Hom}(FGB,B') $$
coming from applying $G$ and then using adjointness is given explicitly as $g\mapsto g\varepsilon_B$.

The result is now clear: $G$ is fully faithful if and only if this composition is always an isomorphism, which is if and only if $\varepsilon$ is a natural isomorphism.

Comment: I'm looking at naturality condition (2.3) which I added to the question. As far as I can see, in our case it is $\overline{G(g)\circ f}=\overline{G(g)}\circ F(f)$. This doesn't seem to agree with what you have. Did you apply the same equation (2.3)?

Comment: You should use (2.2) to get $\overline{g\circ\bar f}=G(g)\circ f$, and then apply the bar again to get $g\circ\bar f=\overline{G(g)\circ f}$. Sorry for the notation conflict, but I didn‘t have Leinster‘s book to hand.

Comment: By the way, the same reasoning also gives that $G$ is faithful if and only if the counit is always epi, and there are analogous results for $F$ and the unit.

Comment: In the last paragraph, do you mean isomorphism in $\textbf{Set}$? That is, is this the right statement: "$G$ is fully faithfull iff the map of sets $g\mapsto g\epsilon_B$ is a bijection"? And then I guess you're using that $\epsilon$ is known to be a natural transformation, so it's a natural isomorphism iff each $\epsilon_B$ is an isomorphism in $\mathscr B$; and the latter happens iff $g\mapsto g\epsilon_B$ is a bijection.

Comment: Yes, and yes :)

Comment: I'm a little confused about the proof that if the composite map is a bijection, then $\epsilon_B$ is an isomorphism. Injectivity implies that $\epsilon_B$ is an epimorphism. But I don't see how to use this and surjectivity to prove that $\epsilon_B$ is an isomorphism. (This exercise is given before the discussion of epics/monics/split monics, etc., so I would prefer avoiding this terminology unless it's absolutely necessary.)

Comment: You’re right, this deserved a little more explanation. Assume $G$ is fully faithful. Taking $B’$ to be $FGB$ shows that $\epsilon_B$ has a left inverse $g$. Then both $\mathrm{id}_B$ and $\epsilon_Bg$ are sent to $\epsilon_B$, and since it’s a bijection we deduce that $g$ is also a right inverse.

Comment: Thanks! I'll also leave a note (primarily for my reference in the future): one could also use Lemma 2.2.4 from Leinster to show that the composition is given by $g\mapsto \epsilon_{B'}\circ FG(g)$ and then one could use that $\epsilon:FG\to 1_\mathscr B$ is a natural transformation to conclude that $\epsilon_{B'}\circ FG(g)=g\circ \epsilon_B$ so that the composition in question is given by $g\mapsto g\circ \epsilon_B$.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can do this from scratch as follows:

first, prove a lemma: for any arrows $x, y :
b'\to b$ in $\mathscr B$, we have $x\circ \epsilon_b = y\circ \epsilon_{b'} \Leftrightarrow Gx = Gy:$

Since $\epsilon$ is a natural transformation, we have $x\circ \epsilon_{b'}=\epsilon_{b}\circ FGx$ and similarly for $y$. Then, $x\circ \epsilon_b = y\circ \epsilon_b\Leftrightarrow \epsilon_{b}\circ FGx=\epsilon_{b}\circ FGy\Leftrightarrow \overline {Gx}=\overline {Gy}\Leftrightarrow Gx=Gy$, the last equality true because $^-$ is a bijection.

Now, if $\epsilon$ is an isomorphism then in particular, it is epic, so the lemma says $x=y\Leftrightarrow Gx=Gy$; that is, $G$ is faithful. On the other hand, if $G$ is faithful, then the lemma says that $\epsilon$ is epic.

Continuing, if $G$ is full, then then there is an arrow $x : b\to FGb$ such that $Gx = \eta_{Gb}.$ An application of a triangular identity (which one?) and the naturality of $\epsilon$ show that $1_{FGb} =x\circ \epsilon_b$ so $\epsilon$ is a split monic.

We have now that if $G$ is fully faithful then $\epsilon$ is an isomorphism.

Finally, let $f:Gb'\to Gb$  and suppose that $\epsilon_b'$ is a split monic.  Then, there is a morphism $x:b'\to FGb'$ such that $x\circ \epsilon_{b'}=1_{FGb'}$.  Then, $\overline {Gx}=1_{FGb'}=\overline {\eta_{Gb'}}$ so $Gx= \eta_{Gb'}$ and another application of the triangular identities gives $G(\epsilon_b \circ F f\circ  x)=f$; i.e. $G$ is full.