# Condition in proof of unit of adjoint is isom iff F fully faithful.

Tags: category-theory

[Let $C,D$ be categories and $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to C$ be adjoint functors. Then $F$ is fully faithful iff the unit is an isomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994963/let-c-d-be-categories-and-fc-to-d-and-gd-to-c-be-adjoint-functors-then?newreg=139b81d8d63e4b61ae91fbcc86e075e5)

Regarding this proof in the first comment, in the part where he proves that $F$ is full if $\eta$ is split epic, how does he go from
$GF(f) = G(g)$ to $F(f) = g?$

This must require that $G$ is invertible?

Additionally in the final line of the proof, how do you do a similar thing to remove the $F$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, what we use is not $GF(f)=G(g)$ but really $GF(f)\circ \eta_X=G(g)\circ \eta_X$; and similarly, in the second case, what we use is $\epsilon_{FX} \circ F(\eta_X\circ s_X)=\epsilon_{FX}\circ F(id_{GFX})$. The reason these equations imply $F(f)=g$ and $\eta_X\circ s_X=id_{GFX}$ is that the maps
$$\theta_{X,FY}^{-1}:h\in\operatorname{Hom}_D(FX,FY)\mapsto G(h)\circ \eta_X\in \operatorname{Hom}_C (X, GFY)$$
and
$$\theta_{GFX,FX}:k\in\operatorname{Hom}_C(GFX,GFX)\mapsto \epsilon_{FX} \circ F(k)\in \operatorname{Hom}_C(FGFX,FX)$$
are two components of the natural isomorphism $\theta:\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(- ,G-)\to \operatorname{Hom}_{D}(F- ,-)$ defining the adjunction $F\dashv G$, and thus in particular they must be injective.