# How to use Yoneda's lemma in proving: $F$ fully-faithful iff unit is an isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, yoneda-lemma

Let $F \dashv G$ be an adjunction with unit $e: Id \implies GF$.

It is well known that $e$ is an isomorphism if and only $F$ is fully-faithful. I've a proof of this fact that doesn't use Yoneda's lemma in any explicit way.

Here: [Let $C,D$ be categories and $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to C$ be adjoint functors. Then $F$ is fully faithful iff the unit is an isomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994963/let-c-d-be-categories-and-fc-to-d-and-gd-to-c-be-adjoint-functors-then/1994972#1994972)
it is mentioned that using the Yoneda lemma can solve this question almost directly. Can you elaborate on how?

For instance, even in the direction $e$ is an isomorphism implies $F$ is fully-faithful, the only way I see to use the Yoneda lemma doesn't shorten my direct proof.

For the other direction I'm actually not sure how to use explicitly.

By using Yoneda's lemma I mean use either:

1. The Yoneda functor $Y$ is fully-faith
2. There is an isomorphism between Fun$(Y(x), F)$ and $F(x)$ where $F$ is a presheaf

How can the Yoneda lemma be used to prove this claim easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)\stackrel{\eta_B\circ-}{\to}\mathsf{Hom}(A,GFB)\stackrel{\varphi_{A,FB}}{\cong}\mathsf{Hom}(FA,FB)$$ natural in $A$ and $B$ with $\eta$ being the unit. This would immediately make fullness and faithfulness of $F$ be equivalent to $\eta$ being an isomorphism (via Yoneda) as long as we can show that $Ff=\varphi(\eta\circ f)$. Specifically, we'd have $$\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)\stackrel{F}{\cong}\mathsf{Hom}(FA,FB)\stackrel{\varphi^{-1}_{A,FB}}{\cong}\mathsf{Hom}(A,GFB)$$ is equal to $$\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)\stackrel{\eta_B\circ-}{\to}\mathsf{Hom}(A,GFB)$$ meaning it's an isomorphism and Yoneda (like all fully faithful functors) reflects isomorphisms. The other direction is obvious: $F$ would be a composition of isomorphisms.

The necessary equality is immediate by naturality of $\varphi$ (in $A$ as above) which lets us reduce to $Fid=id=\varphi(\eta)$ and indeed $\eta$ is defined as (or provably equivalent to) as $\varphi^{-1}(id)$. (In the cases where $\eta$ is primitive, then the definition of $\varphi$ and its inverse will make the above equation fairly obvious.)