# Relation between right adjoints and counits

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

Assume that $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is left adjoint to $G: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ with counit $\varepsilon: F G \Rightarrow$ id $_{\mathcal{D}}$ and unit $\eta$ : id $_{\mathcal{C}} \Rightarrow G F$. Show that
$$
\mathcal{D}\left(d_{1}, d_{2}\right) \stackrel{\varepsilon^{*}}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{D}\left(F G d_{1}, d_{2}\right) \stackrel{\text { adjunction }}{\cong} \mathcal{C}\left(G d_{1}, G d_{2}\right)
$$
is the functor $G$. Conclude that

1. $G$ is faithful if and only if each arrow $\varepsilon_{d}: F G d \rightarrow d$ is an epimorphism;
2. $G$ is full if and only if each arrow $\varepsilon_{d}: F G d \rightarrow d$ is a split monomorphism;
3. $G$ is full and faithful if and only if $\varepsilon$ is an isomorphism.

I know this question has been answered before: [Let $C,D$ be categories and $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to C$ be adjoint functors. Then $F$ is fully faithful iff the unit is an isomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994963/let-c-d-be-categories-and-fc-to-d-and-gd-to-c-be-adjoint-functors-then)

However, I'm confused about

> Show that $$ \mathcal{D}\left(d_{1}, d_{2}\right) \stackrel{\varepsilon^{*}}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{D}\left(F G d_{1}, d_{2}\right) \stackrel{\text { adjunction }}{\cong} \mathcal{C}\left(G d_{1}, G d_{2}\right) $$ is the functor $G$.

I've never seen the notation $\varepsilon^*$ before which makes me hesitant to write out an explicit answer. Indeed, it seems trivial but I might be misunderstanding some subtlety. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $f^*$ is the notation for _precomposition_ with $f$: it sends a map $g$ to $g \circ f$. Some also call it "pulling back".

Comment: But it seems to be a weird pullback qhere only one component is pulled back- As far as I know, $\varepsilon$ is a natural iso between the identity functor of §D§ and the functor $FG$.

Comment: And it has a component at $d_1$, giving a morphism $F G d_1 \to d_1$. Writing subscripts all the time is laborious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry people think the identity your presenting is trivial. It's really not. You can check out the proposition labeled **(pre/post-composition with (co-)unit followed by adjunct is adjoint functor)** [here](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/geometry+of+physics+%E2%80%93+basic+notions+of+category+theory#ReExpressingMiddleFunctorInAdjointTriple).

With regards to the subsequent implications check out Proposition 2.4 in  [nLab's page on adjoint functors](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/adjoint+functor).

Hope this answered any remaining questions.